# Using AppCode with Flutter plugin

Tags: swift, flutter, cocoapods, appcode

How can I use AppCode for the ios-specific parts of my Flutter plugin?

I've created the plugin with `flutter create --template=plugin --platforms=ios myplugin`

The command doesn't generate an XCode project or workspace for the plugin itself but it includes an example app for which it does generate these. Running `flutter build ios` in `example` then creates symlinks to the plugin code in `example/ios/.symlinks` that I can use to edit the actual Swift code with auto completion, code navigation etc. When I open these files in AppCode however, I get the below error and no coding assistance is available at all:

[image]

Comment: I think AppCode is a great complementary IDE to Xcode. Have you got it working so far, or did you abandon it? 

Answer (score 0):

I previously used AppCode quite a lot to maintain some Flutter plugins' iOS code (but switched jobs and didn't need AppCode or Xcode). However, I recently started making a free app, and also wanted to contribute to a Flutter plugin for iOS, I wanted AppCode again. *I got AppCode working again, so I wanted to share.*

In your flutter directory:

- For editing/debugging/running Flutter apps' iOS code: run `appcode ios`
- For Flutter plugins, run `appcode example/ios` (**not** `appcode ios`)

Some principles:

- The files don't show up immediately, use Command + Shift + O to find your file. Then Opt + F1 to show it in the project navigator.
- Built at least once using `flutter run` or Xcode (to make sure configuration is set up).
- You cannot escape Xcode. Xcode and AppCode are complementary. Find the balance . Refactoring code, debugging the application, searching and reading code works really well in AppCode. Xcode does reading configuration better or *debugging builds*.
- If you get random errors (e.g. everything fails but the error is `build failed` in AppCode, you should open in Xcode or build/run the flutter app for iOS: `flutter run` and read the error messages.
- If you want to debug both Flutter and iOS simultaneously, start the iOS debugger, then "Flutter attach" in android studio (maybe this is possible in VSCode too, but I don't use that).

---

Here's an example screenshot of AppCode with debugger working. You might be curious if *telemetry* flag you set in Flutter was actually being set in the iOS side... maybe there's a bug. But I take privacy seriously and confirm the telemetry is disabled. I also watch network traffic sometimes. . If you're interested, you can then follow that to it's dependencies (manually, using by reading `package.swift`), and find out it is set to true by default.

```
        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [
            #keyPath(UserDefaults.MGLMapboxMetricsEnabled): true
        ])
```

[image: AppCode screenshot with debugger]